# Changing Google Play device filters after releasing app?

Tags: android, google-play

I know that we can set various filters to prevent incompatible devices from downloading an app.
If a filter is set up to prevent downloads, can it be changed later without uploading a new apk?

The reason I ask is that our app works on most Android devices, but we have Xperia Play and HTC One X+ users saying that it has crashed after the splash screen.

If we can temporarily block those devices until we find the reason, it will prevent people from spending their money on an app they can't use (and giving us a low rating to reflect that). Then once the problem is fixed, we could simply remove the filter and reallow those devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually exclude devices within the Play Store console (only found it in the classic rather than the new layout).

It's titled Supported Devices within the publishing options section just below the countries list.

You can add/remove devices at any time but it will take several hours for the new availability to spread worldwide.

Comment: As a follow up the new design of the play store console also has manual device exclusion, it's under the APK's tab.

Comment: Thank you. I knew we could exclude the device, just wasn't sure we could re-include it so easily.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to upload a new apk.

Login to the developer console (it defaults to the new UI now so I'm providing steps for that) and then do the following:

1. Open the page for your app
2. Go to the apk tab from the sidebar
3. Click `See supported devices`
4. Find the devices you want to exclude and then click the green check mark. It should change to a red ban sign.

Repeat 4. for all the devices you want to exclude.